# Cannot locate an element using By.xpath

Tags: java, selenium

I am on the following page : [URL](https://message.alibaba.com/msgsend/contact.htm?spm=a2700.details.maonnacta.dmessage.35f27552gNzeS&action=contact_action&domain=1&id=60449828505&id_f=IDX1eJR5RAxxTgliuJtCjLiQK4LPSRmesIX8tQWEpFLhdsmyylMs_oCrTyvia2XxGXRQ&mloca=main_en_detail&tracelog=tracedetailfeedback&umidToken=Bf9569377c353a415c18b826024db1857)

Trying to access the `Send Inquiry Now` button using following webelement access details

```
element2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                        .xpath("//input[@value='Send Inquiry Now']")));
        element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Send Inquiry Now']"));
```

But getting error like

```
Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //input[@value='Send Inquiry Now']
```

WHY?

Though xPath is locating the element when i am trying through FirePath.

Comment: are you sure you are getting this exception and not timedoutException in the first line.

Comment: Can you give the whole exception log

Comment: Are you getting timeout exception?

Comment: This is total exception log:


WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //input[@value='Send Inquiry Now' and @type='submit'])
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //input[@value='Send Inquiry Now' and @type='submit']

Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
 at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 12);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@value='Send Inquiry Now']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Send Inquiry Now']")).click();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Rather than presence, use visible or clickable. Presence just means it's in the DOM and can still cause problems if it's not visible/clickable yet. My general rule is if I'm going to click the element then I wait for clickable, if not use visible.

Comment: Also, the `wait.until()` returns the element waited for so you can just do `wait.until(...).click()`. The way you have it written you actually scrape the page until its there... then you scrape the page again to click it.

Comment: I didn't downvote but code only answers are many time not very useful. It's better if you take a minute to explain what your code does and why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The following code block without any `wait` works fine at my end to click on the `Send Inquiry Now` button:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Q45166267_Alibaba 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://message.alibaba.com/msgsend/contact.htm?spm=a2700.details.maonnacta.dmessage.35f27552gNzeS&action=contact_action&domain=1&id=60449828505&id_f=IDX1eJR5RAxxTgliuJtCjLiQK4LPSRmesIX8tQWEpFLhdsmyylMs_oCrTyvia2XxGXRQ&mloca=main_en_detail&tracelog=tracedetailfeedback&umidToken=Bf9569377c353a415c18b826024db1857");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Send Inquiry Now' and @type='submit']")).click();
    }
}
```

> It is worth to mention that the URL takes a bit long to load, so in-case if you face `ElementNotFound` exception you have to induce `ExplicitWait` with `ExpectedConditions` set for `elementToBeClickable` (instead of `presenceOfElementLocated`) as follows:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Q45166267_Alibaba 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://message.alibaba.com/msgsend/contact.htm?spm=a2700.details.maonnacta.dmessage.35f27552gNzeS&action=contact_action&domain=1&id=60449828505&id_f=IDX1eJR5RAxxTgliuJtCjLiQK4LPSRmesIX8tQWEpFLhdsmyylMs_oCrTyvia2XxGXRQ&mloca=main_en_detail&tracelog=tracedetailfeedback&umidToken=Bf9569377c353a415c18b826024db1857");
        WebDriverWait wait10 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element10 = wait10.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Send Inquiry Now' and @type='submit']")));
        element10.click();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: this is not working with me. And i guess the reason is you have hit this page directly , 

but i am navigating to this page from https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Cover-for-Mac-book-Striped-Laptop_60571814719.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.1.Go4l3N&s=p

then clicking on Contact Supplier , i am getting this page where i have to click "Send Inquiry Now" button. Though the Quantity field and Message area element inside the iframe are successfully accessible to me. but unfortunately not the button "Send Inquiry Now".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem myself.

Actually i was inside the iframe to access the text area. and then right after that, was locating the button "Send Inquiry button". Which was not inside that iframe.

So i first switch to default using following:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

And then access the "Send Inquiry Now". Which works successfully.